# string to number function is not turning string to numbers

Tags: rust

So I have this function which is supposed to turn string to a number:

```rust
fn to_number(string: &mut String) {
    string.trim().parse::<u32>().expect("Error");
}
```

If I were to use it though, it doesn't seem to change the variable passed to it:

```
let mut x: String = " 12 ".into();
to_number(&mut x);
let y = x / 2; // Error here
```

The error produced:

```
cannot multiply `{integer}` by `String`
the trait `Mul<String>` is not implemented for `{integer}`
the following other types implement trait `Mul<Rhs>`:
\<&'a f32 as Mul\<f32\>\>
\<&'a f64 as Mul\<f64\>\>
\<&'a i128 as Mul\<i128\>\>
\<&'a i16 as Mul\<i16\>\>
\<&'a i32 as Mul\<i32\>\>
\<&'a i64 as Mul\<i64\>\>
\<&'a i8 as Mul\<i8\>\>
\<&'a isize as Mul\<isize\>\>
and 49 others
```

I've tried to shadow the passed string, but it still not changing the variable to a number.

Comment: Did you mean to use `String` and not `string`? Is that a typo when copying code over to Stack Overflow?

Comment: You never assign to the variable `string` in the `to_number` function, so the output will be ignored. You couldn't assign a different type to a variable anyways. Why not return a value instead?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot change the type of a variable.

What your functions does is parsing the string into a number, then throwing the result out of the window.

You need to return it from the function, then rebind it, possibly with the same name (but they're still different variables):

```rust
fn to_number(string: &str) -> u32 {
    string.trim().parse::<u32>().expect("Error")
}

let x: String = " 12 ".into();
let x = to_number(&x);
let y = x / 2;
```